# "User who unpublished" in Storage Extension

Tags: web8.5, storage-extensions, unpublishing

We have implemented Storage Extension in Tridion Deployer to push the content to  a thrid-party storage. This third-party storage has got a requirement to capture the name of the user who publishes/unpublishes the content.

Our Tridion Template adds the user info to the published content. As Template gets executed while publishing and published content itself includes the user info, third-party storage gets the info needed. However no Template is executed while unpublishing. If I check the transport package created while unpublishing, it doesn't have any information about the user who unpublished.

How can I get "user who unpublished" in Storage Extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've realized, this cannot be achieved using templating. If you wish to do this this way, you will need to use a different extension point, namely `ITransportPackageHandler`.
See my TDS presentation for more information [here](https://vimeo.com/290357613).

But... why don't you do this on the CM side? Make use of the Event System and the `SetPublishStateEventArgs` class. This is only executed on successful publishes, so you only need to check whether it's unpublish. Additionally, this has the  `Publisher` property which is the user who initiated the transaction.

Comment: Thanks Atila. It helps.